# unable to load functional component into App.js React

Tags: reactjs

this is my component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function SearchField() {
    return (
      <p>test</p>
    );
  }

  export default SearchField;
```

And this is App.js which loads SearchField component:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import '../src/Components/SearchField';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <SearchField></SearchField>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm getting SearchField is undefined.

Comment: You need to give the name of the component while importing.. Try like ```import SearchField from '../src/components/searchfield';
``` ..

Comment: Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-cherry-8i8hh

Comment: You need to default import the `SearchField` component in `App`, i.e. `import SearchField from '../src/Components/SearchField';`. Voting to close as unreproducible or caused by typo. Cheers.